# Map inside list, Want to retrieve all maps and store its values to another list

Tags: java, spring

I have record returned by `jdbcTemplate` in `List<Map<k,V>>`, i want to fetch only `Map<K,V>` and then i want to add V in another `List` and returned that list to controller and show into the jsp

```
    public List<Object> searchByempCodeV2(String tabSuffix, String empCode, String yyyyMm) {
    List<Object> targetList = null;
    MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    String tableName = "Salary_detail_report_082018";
    String query = "SELECT "
            + " DISTINCT PAY_CODE, "
            + " PAY_CODE_DESC, "
            + " AMOUNT, "
            + " row_number() over (Order by EMP_CODE ) AS ROW_NUM "
            + " FROM " + tableName
            + " WHERE EMP_CODE=" + empCode
            + " AND YYYYMM=" + yyyyMm
            + " AND PAY_CODE NOT IN (997,998,999) "
            + " ORDER BY PAY_CODE ASC ";
    List<Map<String, Object>> employees = queryForList(query);
    if (employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()) {
        for (Map<String, Object> employee : employees) {
            targetList = new ArrayList<>(employee.values());

        }
    }
    return targetList;
}
```

}

right now my `targetList` returned only the last record,provide me the suggestion

Comment: Please do not create SQL queries by joining strings together. You should always use paramterised queries, otherwise you have a significant security risk from SQL injection.

Comment: What is `queryForList` and why does it return a Map?

Comment: thanks mate, but this is beta phase, we are not in production yet, this will also implemented in code optimisation phase, kindly suggest me what i exactly ask about.

Comment: @ScaryWombat querForList()  belongs to JdbcTemplate API, and it returns List of Map<K,V>

Comment: It returns only the last record because you assign `targetList = new ArrayList<>(employee.values());` in each `for` iteration - so you replace the reference each time and at the end there is a reference to the last entry from the map.

Comment: There is no need to test employee for being empty, as the for loop just won't iterate over an empty list.
`param` doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: @cgrim can you demonstrate the fix in the same post

Comment: @user9634982 I added that as an answer - I hope it is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first create the list instance:

```
List<Collection<Object>> targetList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then fill in the list during the iteration:

```
    for (Map<String, Object> employee : employees) {
        targetList.add(employee.values());
    }
```

See the difference: `add()` call instead of assignment by `=`.

So at the end you will have `List<Collection<Object>>`.